# Help with mechanism: Isomerization of eugenol

Tags: reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, phenols

I'm confused about the mechanism for the isomerization of the external alkene eugenol to the internal alkene isoeugenol. I've added an image below of their structures.

[image]

The reaction is usually carried out using a strong base (sodium or potassium hydroxide) in a polyol solvent (typically glycerol or ethylene glycol).

I have no idea why this might happen, especially given that there's no carbonyls with acidic alpha carbons in the molecule. Maybe eugenol phenoxide is responsible?

Comment: Looks like a sigmatropic rearrangement.

Comment: [1,3] sigmatropic shift?

Comment: It is thought to be a two-step reaction with cis-iso-eugenol as an intermediate as described [here](http://file.upi.edu/Direktori/FPMIPA/JUR._PEND._KIMIA/196305091987031-R._ASEP_KADAROHMAN/%5B1%2C3%5D%20SIGMATROPIC%20REARRANGEMENT.pdf). The direct 1,3 sigmatropic reararrangement to the trans product has a symmetry problem.